# Is is possible to download the terraform output as a .json file?

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

Can the output in terraform be saved locally on my system as a .json file. I need to know if this is possible as this .json file will be used by spot hence why I need to generate it.

Comment: What do you mean by the JSON file will be used by spot?

Comment: The service once known as spotinst has not been changed to spot. The clusters we use are managed my spot

Answer (score 2):

Run this after you apply to get the outputs as JSON:

```
terraform show -json > output.json
```

The [Terraform Command: show (JSON Output)](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/show.html#json-output) section in the Terraform documentation explains this further.